# Style the dropdown element of Material UI Select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to customize the design (borders, radius border) of the drop-down element of the Material UI `Select` component.

The Material UI documentation mentions various properties to override and style the various sub-components, but none for the drop-down itself. The reason for it might be that the drop-down renders out of the root component, with the position absolute relative to the page.

Any idea how I can style the dropdown?
Here is a screenshot of the current state of the component:

[image]

I was able to customize the design of the input element of the Material UI `Select` component

Comment: The best idea is to read the source codes instead of their documents, the docs are good but codes are way more clear.

Comment: I suggest to clone the whole repository and set the commit to your package version, then you should easily find how to customize the style object.

Comment: Reading the source code is a good idea. Forking and changing the repository for something like this, not so much.

Answer (score 42):

You can use the `sx` prop in **Material UI v5** to style the `Paper` which contains a list of `MenuItem` inside like this:

```
<Select
  fullWidth
  value={age}
  onChange={handleChange}
  MenuProps={{
    PaperProps: {
      sx: {
        bgcolor: 'pink',
        '& .MuiMenuItem-root': {
          padding: 2,
        },
      },
    },
  }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 28):

## Material-UI v4

You can do that in **two different** ways:

#### 1. At global level

This way all the menus in the application will get the style.

First you need to create a `theme.js` file:

```js
'use strict';

import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        // Applied to the <ul> element
        MuiMenu: {
            list: {
                backgroundColor: "#cccccc",
            },
        },
        // Applied to the <li> elements
        MuiMenuItem: {
            root: {
                fontSize: 12,
            },
        },
    },
});

export default theme;
```

Then import it in your main application component, so it will be applied to all the application components:

```js
'use strict';

import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from 'theme.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                    {/* Your app content */}
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

#### 2. At component level

With this approach you can define a different menu style for each component.

```js
'use strict';

import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    select: {
        "& ul": {
            backgroundColor: "#cccccc",
        },
        "& li": {
            fontSize: 12,
        },
    },
});

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    const classes = useStyles();

    render() {
        return (
            <Select MenuProps={{ classes: { paper: classes.select } }} />
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have the exact environment I had a year ago, but I tried this in isolation, and WOW, it worked like a charm.
Thanks @luca-fagioli! 
I hope it also helps others like me.

Comment: Can you add more detail here?  The Component level solution has to be missing detail because I get an error that classes is not defined.  I also tried your Global solution and it had no effect.  Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @Mideus I have added a more exhaustive example, with more details. Hopefully it will be enough for you to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, got it working! However, I also need to style the main control not just the menu/items. Any ideas? I need to change the border color. Here's my code:
`<FormControl variant="outlined"><InputLabel id="id">Parent</InputLabel><Select labelId="id" name="PID" label="Parent" value={pid}>{...MenuItems}</Select></FormControl>`

Comment: Glad you got it working. For your next problem, you'd better ask a new question here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Wont setting MenuProps override all props specified in theme ?

Comment: @ErikParso They are two different approaches, one global and one for each individual menu. I've edit the answer so hopefully I made it clearer. Let me know.

Comment: after hours of searching finally

Answer (score 21):

**For Material-ui version 0**

Apply styles to dropdownMenuprops as stated here [Select Properties](https://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field)

```js
const dropdownMenuProps={
  menuStyle:{
    border: "1px solid black",
    borderRadius: "5%",
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
  },
}
```

Apply the style to select using dropdownmenuprops

```html
<SelectField
        multiple={true}
        hintText="Overriden"
        value={values}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        dropDownMenuProps={dropdownMenuProps}
      >
```

[SandBox Demo using version 0.18](https://codesandbox.io/s/38w9o3vw8p)

**For Material-ui Version 1**

Dropdown or menu styles are overriden using MenuProps property.

[Select-API](https://material-ui-next.com/api/select/)

Try this

```js
const styles = theme => ({
    dropdownStyle: 
    {
      border: "1px solid black",
      borderRadius: "5%",
      backgroundColor:'lightgrey',
    },
});
```

Apply the style to MenuProps

```html
 <Select
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-simple"
            }}
            MenuProps={{ classes: { paper: classes.dropdownStyle } }}
          >
```

I tried this in codesandbox and it works for me

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/x91yvol354)

Read the API of [Menu](https://material-ui-next.com/api/menu/) and [Select](https://material-ui-next.com/api/select/) for more details.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using the beta version.

Comment: This doesn't work https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VlPxH04n7qdLo7WmNkX9owrELNK5CMIA . Box-shadow is a property of the parent div, and there doesn't seem to be any api to target the style of that div.

Comment: @anonymous_siva I am trying to solve a similar problem. Although I want to extend this solution further. 
By updating style for `paper` I was able to fix the outer content of the drop-down elements. The next thing I want to target is the `ul` that encapsulates the `li`/`MenuItems`. I just couldn't figure out a way to do that.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the `withStyles` complexity (as in your sandbox)? Is there some way just to set the properties directly in an attribute of the component?

Comment: is there a way to change the border color of the input?

Comment: @darth-coder did you already figured out how to do what you are asking? I have the same problem with you.

Comment: @bossajie My answer may help you.

Answer (score 6):

**For anyone still looking for this in 2022:**

```
             MenuProps={{
                sx: {
                    '& .MuiMenu-paper': {
                        backgroundColor: 'dark.primary',
                        color: 'text.light'
                    },
                    '& .MuiMenuItem-root:hover': {
                        backgroundColor: 'dark.secondary',
                        color: 'text.white'
                    },
                    '& .Mui-selected': {
                        backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
                        color: 'text.white'
                    }
                }
            }}
            sx={{
                color: '#fff',
                '&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                    borderColor: 'red',
                },
                '.MuiSvgIcon-root': {
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                '&:before': {
                    borderBottom: `1px solid ${DarkTheme.palette.primary.light}`
                },
                '&:hover': {
                    ':before': {
                        borderBottom: `1px solid ${DarkTheme.palette.primary.dark}`
                    }
                },
                '& .MuiMenuItem-root': {
                    backgroundColor: 'dark.primary'
                },
                '& .MuiMenu-paper': {
                    backgroundColor: 'dark.primary'
                }
            }}
```