# Material UI - MultiSelect Popup Anchor Moving on Select

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I noticed this when upgrading from Material UI 4.2.0 to 4.9.10, but through troubleshooting, I believe this behavior started with version 4.8.3

When using a Select with the multiple attribute, the popup menu moves upon selection of the first item.  I have other examples where it moved several times as multiple items are selected, but in the example I'm providing here, it seems to just happen when choosing the first item.  Here's a codesandbox demonstrating this: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-morse-2omxy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Here's the same code sample, but using Material UI 4.8.2.  When I choose items from this example, the menu remains anchored to where it was when it popped up: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-frost-pxlds?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

My preferred behavior here is the second example, where the menu doesn't jump around on me as I'm selecting.  I've looked through the API, and have tried specifying different anchors, but so far have not been able to keep the popup menu from moving around.  Does anyone know of how to keep the menu in place with version 4.8.3 and beyond?

Answer (score 13):

Turns out that this is a Material UI bug that's targeted to be fixed in version 5.  Here is a workaround until then:

```
    <Select
        MenuProps={{
            getContentAnchorEl: () => null,
        }}
```

Answer (score 9):

@JoshSchmitton's answer did not work for me with Typescript as the type for getContentAnchorEl is `((element: Element) => Element) | null | undefined` However the following slight modification achieves the desired result:

```
<Select
        MenuProps={{
            getContentAnchorEl: null,
        }} />
```

Thank you Josh Schmitton

Answer (score 2):

You can create object:

```
const MenuProps = {
    getContentAnchorEl: null,
    PaperProps: {
        style: {
            maxHeight: 200,
            width: 300,
        },
    },
};
```

and then

```
<Select MenuProps={MenuProps}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, the result will be nearly the same with current version 5 material UI.

`getContentAnchorEl` to `null` is used to fix the drop-down's position.

And the rest of the props is used for move the drop-down lower but not overlap with the input field.

```
<Select
    MenuProps={{
        getContentAnchorEl: () => null,
        anchorOrigin: { vertical: 'bottom', horienter code herezontal: 'center' },
        transformOrigin: { vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' },
    }} />
```

Answer (score -1):

If you add this to the Select then it will prevent the dropdown from moving regardless of the amount of items selected:

`<Select MenuProps={{ autoFocus: true }} />`

Comment: I just tried what you suggested, but the "jumping" on the selection of the first item is still occurring, at least for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-gauss-syhfr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @JoshSchmitton, I think I understand your question. Just to be clear, you want to display the select, below the input field. I believe you will have to set a menuProps on the `Select`. This is what I found:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/5634
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353676/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-dropdown-element-of-the-material-ui-select-compon

It looks to be available on the Select Api

Comment: Actually, I think forcing it below the input field will be too limiting.  I'm fine with it popping up wherever it wants, and prefer that it does that.  But want I don't want is for the popup to move when I select the first item from it.  For example, in the first codesandbox on my original post, when I choose 'Carlos Abbott', the location of the popup menu moves to a different position.  In the second codesandbox (using the older version of MUI), it behaves the way I want in that the menu pops up wherever it wants, but stays anchored to its position

Comment: Understood. If you add this to the `Select` then it will prevent the dropdown from moving regardless of the amount of items selected:

`MenuProps={{  autoFocus: true }}`

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but I applied (copied) the MenuProps you list it and made it one of the Select attributes, no difference.