# MUI Select disappears out of screen

Tags: material-ui

I am using MUI Select for result filters but the popup disappears out of the screen by a small amount which makes it look as if there are more options.

[image]

I have tried the following but with no success:

- adding a margin to the Select
- adding a class to the Select with margin
- adding `disableScrollLock: true` to the MenuProps
- adding a class to FormControl

Here is my code:

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl} size="small" fullWidth >
      <div
        className="filter-title"
        style={{ color: "black", marginBottom: "0.5em" }}
      >
        {fieldName}
      </div>
      <Select
        disabled={disabled}
        multiple
        value={selectedItems}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderValue={(selected: any) => {
          if (selected.length !== 0) {
            return (
              <span style={{ color: "grey" }}>{selected.length} selected</span>
            );
          } else {
            return <span style={{ color: "grey" }}>All</span>;
          }
        }}
        variant="outlined"
        displayEmpty
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onOpen={handleOpen}
        MenuProps={{
          getContentAnchorEl: (): any => null, // Avoids the popup jumping: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61388096
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem
          key={`${fieldName}_all`}
          value={FILTER_CLEAR_VALUE}
          selected={false}
        >
          <ListItem style={{ color: "#FF725D", fontWeight: 700 }}>
            Clear
          </ListItem>
        </MenuItem>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
            <Checkbox checked={selectedItems.indexOf(option) > -1} />
            <ListItemText primary={option} />
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so in the end it was simply because there was a margin-top added to the popover:

```
.MuiPopover-root#menu- {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Removing this fixed the issue.
Leaving this in case it helps anyone else debug a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally best to provide a sample of your code or a link to an equivalent on CodeSandbox etc.
However, you should simply be able to apply a margin to the `FormControl` (not the Select).

See a working example below ([codesandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-select-without-overflow-phb5k?file=/src/MuiSelect.js))

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  }
}))

export default function DemoSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("")
  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-select-label"
          id="demo-select"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {[...Array(121)].map((e, i) => (
            <MenuItem value={i}>{i + 1}</MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi Snappy, thanks for your suggestion. I have added my code in my answer. I tried adding the class to the FormControl but as I expected, that just adds margin to the form inputs. As you can see in my screenshot, the popup is the issue, as it disappears out of the screen.