# How do I change styles of selected options in MUI Autocomplete component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

The problem is just as in the title, how can I change the style of selected options in MUI while using `multi` option. I would like to change style of al highlighted options. I would really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style the dropdown element of Material UI Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50353676/style-the-dropdown-element-of-material-ui-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [`renderOption`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#Autocomplete-prop-renderOption) prop of a [MUI Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#Autocomplete-prop-renderOption) like so -

```ts
    <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, value) => setValue(value)}
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            label="Multiple values"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
        renderOption={(props, option, state) => {
          return (
            <li
              {...props}
              style={{
                ...props.style,
                ...(state.selected ? { backgroundColor: "yellow" } : {})
              }}
            >
              {option.title}
            </li>
          );
        }}
      />
```

Here's a [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-jepsen-5459w8?file=/Demo.tsx).

Comment: You are a good man, thank you

Comment: You are a god sent! I had been struggling with this for one or two hours!